# Why does Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined occur in esriRequest

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, function, request

I am trying to use `esri/request` to pull in some data from an API. I am have two weird problems. First, when I try to run this, it doesn't complete and throws the following error in the browser console: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined". I am not using `trim()` anywhere and am not sure why this error is being thrown (specifically on the line where I make my `esriRequest`). Second, if I try to test this in the browser by pasting in the function to the console, it says that `esriRequest` is not defined. I have checked the order of my `required` list and functions several times and they look like they are in the proper order. Am I missing something here?

```
require([
    "esri/map",
    "esri/basemaps",
    "esri/dijit/BasemapToggle",
    "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
    "esri/tasks/ImageServiceIdentifyTask",
    "esri/tasks/ImageServiceIdentifyParameters",
    "esri/layers/WebTiledLayer",
    "esri/dijit/Search",
    "esri/config",
    "esri/request",
    "dojo/json",
    "dojo/promise/all", 
    "dojo/domReady!"], function(
        Map, 
        esriBasemaps, 
        BasemapToggle, 
        ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, 
        ImageServiceIdentifyTask, 
        ImageServiceIdentifyParameters, 
        WebTiledLayer, 
        Search, 
        esriConfig, 
        esriRequest, 
        JSON, 
        all) {

        .....
       var url = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/ws/designmaps/asce7-16.json?latitude=18&longitude=-66&riskCategory=I&siteClass=D&title=Default";
      esriRequest(url, {
        responseType: "json"
      }).then(function(response){
        // The requested data
        var seis_data = response.data;
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue with the format of inputs for [esriRequest](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.request-amd.html#esrirequest). You must pass an object as the first parameter, with your url as the value in the "url" property of that object:

```
esriRequest({
    url: url
  }).then(...);
```

[Full example here](https://jsbin.com/dufufibuko/edit?html,js,console,output).

Comment: That was indeed the main issue. Thanks for making the JS Bin example; that was very helpful! Also, thanks for adding the esriConfig with CORS stuff. I immediately ran into that issue when request started working properly and that resolved it.